# Xcode 6: Semantic issues while compiling cocos2d-x project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

Recently I am working on my new project on Xcode 6 with cocos2d-x 3.6

I created the cocos2d-x project using Terminal and I followed the steps of the tutorials below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXqgSNUf9Cc

Obviously, the tutorial is not using Xcode 6.

Sorry for the screen capture because I can't explain the error

http://goo.gl/iyF3uC

My iMac is OS X Yosemite.

Please help me to fix my errors

Thanks.

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is just warning, not error. You can avoid the warning by renaming variables passed as argument, like

```
Point(double x_, double y_) : x{x_}, y{y_} {}
```